# try & catch blocks with implement & interface

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I tried this tutorial : http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/02/create-custom-dialog.html
There is no "hello" debug message when doing  try & catch blocks with implement & interface. Do you think that i can do the try catch block with implement & interface??

```
    private class OnReadyListener implements MyCustomDialog.ReadyListener 
{
  @Override
  public void ready(String name) 
  {  
     try
     {

        String sentence = "hello";
        Log.d(TAG, "OnReadyListener ready"  + " " + sentence );
     }
     catch (UnknownHostException ex) 
     { 
    ex.printStackTrace();   
     }
     catch (IOException ex) 
     {
    ex.printStackTrace();
     }

  }
 }
```

Comment: Yes you can implement try & catch with implement & interface... why you can't?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here but I don't think the fact you have a try / catch should effect this (looks to be testing) code at all. If you debug does the method actually get called?

Answer (score 0):

There is no semi-colon after Log.d()